# yii join table using relations deploy to Linux not work

Tags: php, sql, linux, yii

I using curd to show CGridview  I join 2 table in my computer it work

but when deploy to linux server not work  what wrong? ,help me pls!!

in controller

```
myController


    $model=new UserLogin('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes(); 
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('UserLogin', array( 
                        'criteria' => array(
                        'with'=>'group', 
                    ), 
                        'pagination' => array(
                        'pageSize' => 20, 
                    ),
                ));

        $this->render('admin', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,'model'=>$model)
                          );
```

this error

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

/data/home/nueng/www/html/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php(466)

454 
455     /**
456      * Performs lazy find with the specified base record.
457      * @param CActiveRecord $baseRecord the active record whose related object is to be fetched.
458      */
459     public function lazyFind($baseRecord)
460     {
461         if(is_string($this->_table->primaryKey))
462             $this->records[$baseRecord->{$this->_table->primaryKey}]=$baseRecord;
463         else
464         {
465             $pk=array();
466             foreach($this->_table->primaryKey as $name)
467                 $pk[$name]=$baseRecord->$name;
468             $this->records[serialize($pk)]=$baseRecord;
469         }
470
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum just a guess are you respecting the case in the model name `group` in your `with` criteria?

Linux is case sensitive so if you put `group` instead of `Group` in your relation name or in the model name of the relation an error could occur.